# Maximum Number of Columns in slickgrid

Tags: slickgrid

Does anybody have an information on how to set the maximum number of columns in a slickgrid table? I see that if I have more than 120 columns the new columns appear on a new row in the header section, and what is even worse some columns are hidden.

I am trying to use slickgrid to show excel headers, and I am seeing that when having too many columns slickgrid only optimizes the scrolling of rows and not of columns.

Can anybody guide me in the right direction regarding this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**  Support for virtual rendering on columns has been implemented in SlickGrid v2.1.

This is a bug - you should file it on GitHub.

On the latter, SlickGrid doesn't handle large numbers of columns very well right now, and you have correctly noted that columns are not virtualized like rows.  This is something I'm going to investigate for the next major revision.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When are you planning the release date for the next major version?

Comment: Can't make any promises - I do this in my spare time.

Comment: Regarding first issue - when more than 120 columns are given they are displayed on a new line. Do you have this somewhere in the code that it should display it in a new row? Is this a quick fix that can be changed - some value to be changed from 120 to something new?

Comment: There's a width set to 99999px or something like that on the headers container.  The problem occurs when the total width of all columns exceeds that.

Comment: 120 columns with 100 pixels each add up to 1200 pixels. Way below 99999px ... must be something else

Comment: That's 12'000, not 1'200.  And the width is set at 10'000px.

Comment: Sorry, 12000. Thank you  - I changed the width and it works. They are all displayed in one row ... Sorry to bother you too much, but can you guide me to some literature for virtualizing - I would like to spend time to make the virtualization of the columns possible.

Comment: I'm not aware of any literature on it.  The idea is simple - just render what's in the viewport plus a small buffer.  When you scroll, remove the elements outside the viewport and add the missing ones in.  You can study the SlickGrid code.

Comment: @Tin or imparator - just wondering if there was any traction on virtualised columns - or if you know of any solutions out there?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange The virtual rendering for columns has been implemented in v2.1.